# Parity - Permission Denied, Cannot write version file

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, ubuntu, daemon

I am trying to run a Parity daemon. Here is my shell command:

`sudo parity --db-path . --port=20000 --ws-port=20001 --jsonrpc-port=20002 --jsonrpc-apis web3,parity,parity_accounts,personal,eth daemon parity.pid`

with or without sudo permissions, I am receiving the error message:

`Error upgrading parity data: CannotWriteVersionFile(Os { code: 13, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Permission denied" })`

I have also given 777 permissions to my `db-path` folder with the (spicy and dangerous) command

`sudo chmod 777 -R .`

I am still receiving this error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

My particular problem was that I was trying to make the db_path the root folder on my Digital Ocean volume. For some reason it didn't want to give me write permissions there, so I made a new child folder, and stuck my `db_path` there instead.

```
mkdir db_path //make new folder called db_path 
sudo parity --db-path db_path --port=20000 --ws-port=20001 --jsonrpc-port=20002 --jsonrpc-apis web3,parity,parity_accounts,personal,eth daemon parity.pid
```